# apt-get install -y <program> Para que serve a opção -y?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Não tenho muitos conhecimentos de linux e fiquei com a seguinte dúvida ao realizar a instalação de um novo software no Ubuntu 16:

Para que serve a opção -y do instalador de pacotes apt-get?

Comment: Normalmente a opção `-y` é para não lhe perguntar se realmente deseja fazer `aquilo`. Ele assume que a resposta será `yes`, caso omita isto será perguntado. Por exemplo: `Deseja realmente instalar XX?`, você precisará manualmente dizer `y`. O `-y` as vezes é ignorado por segurança, como em casos onde as assinaturas GPG ou a hash não coincidem, assim irá perguntar se realmente deseja prosseguir, para estes casos existem o `--force-yes`, no `apt-get`, que é inseguro e não recomendado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-y` é por convenção para responder automaticamente sim (*yes*) às questões que possam surgir durante a instalação/update. Sempre que vejas esta flag no comando que delega um determinado processo é muito provável que seja com esta intenção. Evita que esta pergunta aguarde resposta, ex:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

E segue logo implicítamente como se tivesses respondido sim (*Y*).

No caso de `apt-get`, a descrição da flag em `man apt-get` é a seguinte:

> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>              Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such
>   as changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
>   package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get
>              will abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

Tradução:

> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>   Sim automático a *prompts*, assume "sim" como resposta a todos os
>   *prompts* (perguntas) e corre sem interatividade. Se ocorrer uma situação indesejável, como alterar um pacote mantido, tentar instalar
>   um pacote não autenticado ou remoção um pacote essencial, então o
>   processo (apt-get) será abortado.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o `-y` poderia ser traduzido como "instalar sem confirmação".

Quando você usa ele não há necessidade de apertar "S" ou "Y" para confirmar o procedimento de instalação.